# Which commit is HEAD^ after a merge and why isn't it the right one

Tags: git

I have `main`:

```
* 38f4e95 - (HEAD -> main, origin/main) …
* 2abcc91 - nginx configs blue and green …
```

From main, I merge a branch and now I have:

```
*   461eb66 - (HEAD -> main, 
|\  
| * 38f4e95 - (origin/main) .
| * 2abcc91 - nginx configs b
| *   320c676 - Merge branch 
| |\  
| * | 46d0cbd - fix filter (3
* | | 7ea521f - EF Migration
```

I expect **HEAD^** after a commit to be “the HEAD from just before I commited anything” i.e. **38f4e95**. But it isn't, it's a commit from days ago with a whole bunch of work missing. Why?

- Instead HEAD^2 is what I expect to be HEAD^1 (aka HEAD^).
- My habit before merging into main is to first merge from main into branch (so issues are found and fixed in the branch). Does this make a difference?
- Of course the question springs from wanting to undo the merge. It seems like `git reset HEAD^ --hard` should be just the thing for undo last commit, but instead I have to either be really careful or first note down what the “previous” commit was, or else hope that reset from a remote will neatly solves it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the workflow you describe results in *fast-forward* merges:

> My habit before merging into main is to first merge from main into branch (so issues are found and fixed in the branch). Does this make a difference?

This is exactly why it's happening! If you have `my-branch` checked out and merge from `main`, then `main` (commit 38f4e95) is the second parent of that merge commit. When you then switch over to `main` and merge `my-branch`, it's a fast-forward merge so the branches are equivalent at that moment.

Note the first and second parents can't switch based on the point of view- they are "baked into" the commit.

So, yes, if you need to revert, you'll want to double-check the first and second parents to make sure you revert the right direction. You can use `git log --first-parent` to see what `-m1` would yield. (And even just `git log` will display the parent commits for the merge in the proper order.)

**Suggestion:** Here are 2 possible tweaks you could make to your workflow to prevent this from happening in the future (either of these would prevent it, but I personally prefer both):

1. Instead of merging `main` into your feature branch, you could rebase your branch onto `main` to update it. Then you won't be adding "back merges" that could likely get fast-forwarded into `main` which flips the desired parent order.
2. When merging into `main`, choose the `--no-ff` option to force creating a new merge commit. Then the first parent will always be what you expect.

Comment: well, y' know, sometimes it good to add these things to the question just in case they turns out to be relevant or even crucial :-)

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll I bet the commit message (which is cutoff) might hint to it as well. Does it say something like "Merge branch main into my-branch"?

Comment: Ah, yes I see what you mean about the FF merge. That is probably the entire reason isn't it? And yes, if do the merge with `--no-ff` then that generates a merge commit, and now HEAD^ is the commit I expect it to be (the previous commit on main), and HEAD^2 if the previous commit on the child branch.

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll exactly. Doing the back-merge into `my-branch` before `main` gets a new commit enables the FF merge to happen into `main`.

Answer (score 3):

Both `HEAD^1` and `HEAD^2` are parents of your merge commit. There's a nice illustration in `man gitrevisions`:

```
       Here is an illustration, by Jon Loeliger. Both commit nodes B and C are
       parents of commit node A. Parent commits are ordered left-to-right.

           G   H   I   J
            \ /     \ /
             D   E   F
              \  |  / \
               \ | /   |
                \|/    |
                 B     C
                  \   /
                   \ /
                    A

           A =      = A^0
           B = A^   = A^1     = A~1
           C =      = A^2
           D = A^^  = A^1^1   = A~2
           E = B^2  = A^^2
           F = B^3  = A^^3
           G = A^^^ = A^1^1^1 = A~3
           H = D^2  = B^^2    = A^^^2  = A~2^2
           I = F^   = B^3^    = A^^3^
           J = F^2  = B^3^2   = A^^3^2
```

Comment: So it's arbitrary which of e.g. `B` or `C` are `A~1`? Or is there a sequencing over time that's not obvious from the digram?

Comment: I _think_ the branch you're merging into would be the first parent. But I wasn't certain so I left that out of my answer.

Comment: @JasonHemann when ~ is used, it will default to first-parent.